# Equivalents to DISCOS from other agencies

Tags: debris, esa, scientific-data

I'm working on a research paper where the primary data source is going to be the [DISCOSweb API](https://discosweb.esoc.esa.int/).

This API/Dataset provides a wealth of information on manmade object in orbit (debris, payloads, spent stages etc.) as well as launches, launch-vehicles, etc.

However, I'd really like to have other data-sources to cross-validate this set against. I'm primarily interested in databases that contain information about manmade objects in orbit, ideally those that are comprehensive.

Are there any other roughly equivalent data-sets maintained by other agencies?

Comment: Can you edit the question to add more information about what DISCOSweb provides and which parts you're most interested in for the benefit of people who might not have come across it ? Thanks

Comment: @astrosnapper done :)